# Converting a date String with timezone specified to GMT

Tags: java, timezone

I have the following code to parse out a `ZonedDateTime` object from a given date string, the input string is formatted like this:

`"Thu, 03 Mar 2016 02:42:00 +1000 (AEST)"`

My parse code is like this:

```
public ZonedDateTime parseDate(String dateString) throws Exception {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ccc, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z (z)");
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
    ZoneId gmt = ZoneId.of("GMT");
    ZonedDateTime dateTimeInGMT = dateTime.withZoneSameInstant(gmt);
    return dateTimeInGMT;
}
```

and I have this unit test:

```
@Test
public void shouldParseTimezone() throws Exception {
    MailFileParserJava parser = new MailFileParserJava();
    String aestDateTime = "Thu, 03 Mar 2016 02:42:00 +1000 (AEST)"; 
    ZonedDateTime aestZone = parser.parseDate(aestDateTime);
    assertThat(aestZone.getDayOfMonth(), is(2));
    assertThat(aestZone.getHour(), is(16));
}
```

but my unit test is failing on the getHour() assertion -

```
Expected: is <16>
     but: was <15>
```

I don't understand what is going wrong, if I have the time 2:42am, and I subtract the +10 hour offset, then I should get a result of 4:42pm (i.e. hour is 16).

Is there a problem with the way I am converting the string to a `ZonedDateTime` or something else wrong with my code?

EDIT:

Ok, it looks like the time zone conversion stuff I am doing ignores the time zone offset I pass in, and takes into account the actual timezone for the given date (i.e. right now it is daylight savings in Eastern Australia, so the real offset is +1100 instead of +1000).

Now my question is, how can I make Java accept the offset I pass it, instead of it being clever and using its own set of time zone rules to perform the conversion?

Comment: Your aestDateTime date string is wrong. Remove the `Date: ` prefix.

Comment: Sorry, that shouldn't have been there, I still have the same problem

Comment: *"how can I make Java accept the offset I pass it"* @Lashane already told you: **Remove symbolic timezone name (AEST)**

Answer (score 1):

`AEST` time zone is +11 hours right now (DST), so string `+1000` is basically ignored and -11 hours offset is applied

you can either remove symbolic timezone name (AEST) from test and relay only on `+1000` or adjust your test

Answer (score 0):

`AEST` is [`Australia/Sydney`](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/australia/sydney), which observes Daylight Savings Time, and for 2016, DST ends on Apr 3 and starts again on Oct 2.

This means that `03 Mar 2016` is in DST, which is `+1100`, not `+1000`.

`ZonedDateTime.parse` returns:

```
2016-03-03T02:42+11:00[Australia/Sydney]
```

Converting to GMT gives you:

```
2016-03-02T15:42Z[GMT]
```

Debugging your code would have shown you this. I just added print statements for both `dateTime` and `dateTimeInGMT` to see it.